# Why can't Pandas Web Scraping print out any tables from this website?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I wrote this simple code with pandas webscraping which was supposed to extract data from this stocks website. However, once I run this code, it says "list index out of range", meaning that there are no tables on this website. If you open the website though, you can clearly see that there are multiple tables. Could anyone explain how I could fix it?

Website link: https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Single-Stock/Stock-Options?sc_lang=en

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Single-Stock/Stock-Options?sc_lang=en'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

print(len(dfs)) #Gets the row count of the table

print(dfs[0]) #prints the first table
```

Comment: Good catch, good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theere are some inconsistencies with tables in that page, from pandas perspective. Here is one way to get the first table on that page as a dataframe:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd


headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.hkex.com.hk/Products/Listed-Derivatives/Single-Stock/Stock-Options?sc_lang=en'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
spec_table = soup.select('table[class="table migrate"]')[0]
df = pd.read_html(str(spec_table))[0]
print(df[:5].to_markdown())
```

This will return the dataframe:

|  | No. | SEHK Code | Underlying Stock Name | HKATS Code | Contract Size (shares) | Number of Board Lots | Tier No.* | Position Limit ## (Effective from 1 April 2022) | Approved by FSC Taiwan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 16 | Sun Hung Kai Properties Limited | SHK | 1000 | 2 | 1 | 50000 | ✓ |
| 1 | 2 | 175 | Geely Automobile Holdings Ltd. | GAH | 5000 | 5 | 1 | 100000 | ✓ |
| 2 | 3 | 268 | Kingdee International Software Group Co., Ltd. | KDS | 2000 | 2 | 1 | 50000 | nan |
| 3 | 4 | 285 | BYD Electronic International Company Limited | BYE | 1000 | 2 | 1 | 50000 | nan |
| 4 | 5 | 288 | WH Group Ltd. | WHG | 2500 | 5 | 2 | 100000 | nan |

[...]

If you need other tables from page, just isolate them with BeautifulSoup and then read them with pandas.
BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Pandas relevant documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: Thankyou so much, your code worked great! Follow-up question, is there a way I can put this table onto excel through code? I tried using the "to_excel" function but it said "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'"

Comment: For exporting to actual excel you might need some extra stuffs installed on your system. However, exporting to csv should work just fine, just do  `df.to_csv("hkex_output.csv")`. If you really need excel, not csv, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Hi again, sorry I'm new to web scraping so I have a lot of questions. Is there a way to also print out the table below? (the one that starts with CK Hutchison Holdings Ltd. ) 

I tried to do spec_table=soup.select('table[class="table migrate"]')[1] but that just prints out the table even lower (the one about contract summary)

Comment: Hello @NicholasChan. As explained above, there are some inconsistencies with that page's html structure, due to which you need a different technique to reach each particular table. Can you ask a new question, and I will provide a solution?

Comment: Thanks, I just posted a new question